# how to show the exclusion of a value from a series of operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

In my paper I currently have this equation snippet in a bigger equation:

$(A_{1}\oplus A_{2}\oplus \ldots \oplus A_{n})=$

$(A_{1}\oplus \ldots \oplus A_{i-1}\oplus A_{i+1}\oplus \ldots \oplus A_{n})\oplus A_{i} \quad 0\leq i\leq n$

The operation is XOR so it has the associative property. But if we apply i as 0, 1, n-1 and n, the parethensis will look weird, is there any other way to show we took out a number out of a sequence of operations, or this is ok?

Comment: it looks ok for me

Comment: ok thanks a lot!